# How to use close alert and get text

Tags: java, selenium

Every Java code export from selenium ide will have this method..But it is the same with method for iselementpresent because I cant figured out how to use it:

```
private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alert.getText();
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
```

What need to be put exactly in the try code?

Answer (score 1):

The above method is not same as `isElementPresent()`. The `closeAlertAndGetItsText()` method is for handling alert boxes in your web application.

Where ever you need to handle the alert boxes in your web application, you can simply make a call to this `closeAlertAndGetItsText()` method. `closeAlertAndGetItsText()` method will click OK on the alert box and `alert.getText()` will provide you the text that was present in the alert box.

`isElementPresent()` is a method, which you will call when you need to find whether a particular element is present in the webpage or not. There are many implementations of `isElementPresent()` Find below some of them.

```
private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, String id) {
        try {
            driver.getWrappedDriver().findElement(By.id(id));
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, String classname) {
       try {
            driver.findElements(By.className("someclass")).size() > 0;
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks..I'm confuse because I does't know how to change and use them correctly..I will try based on your example..Will share the result..

Thanks @HemChe ..I'm new and not so good in java BTW ..huhuhu